# How to resize and rehash for SeparateChainingHashST?

Tags: rust, hash, iterator

I am implementing the [SeparateChainingHashST](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/SeparateChainingHashST.java.html) in Rust. The complete code can be found [here](https://github.com/ChenZhongPu/algs4-rust/blob/dev/src/searching/separate_chaining_hash_st.rs).

```rust
pub struct SeparateChainingHashST<K, V> {
    n: usize, // number of key-value pairs
    m: usize, // hash table size
    st: Vec<SequentialSearchST<K, V>>,
}
```

, where [SequentialSearchST](https://github.com/ChenZhongPu/algs4-rust/blob/dev/src/searching/sequential_search_st.rs) is a linked list.

What bothers me now is how to implement the `resize` method. Its main idea is: create a new `SeparateChainingHashST` with the new `size`, and then put every key/value into this new symbol table.

What I have done:

```rust
fn resize(self, chains: usize) -> Self {
    let mut tmp = SeparateChainingHashST::new(chains);
    for table in self.st.into_iter() {
        for (k, v) in table.into_items() {
            tmp.put(k, v);
        }
    }
    tmp
}
```

Since `put()` method accepts `K` and `V` by value, I add an into iterator `into_items` to generate `(K, V`).

This version does not really make sense, and what I want is `fn resize(&mut self, chains: usize)`. Note that I don't like to add `Copy` or `Clone` trait to `K` or `V`.

Answer (score 0):

The key point is to take value from `self.st` (a vector), and since the order is not important here, one solution is to use [swap_remove](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.swap_remove):

```rust
fn resize(&mut self, chains: usize) {
    let mut tmp = SeparateChainingHashST::new(chains);
    for _ in 0..self.m {
        for (k, v) in self.st.swap_remove(0).into_items() {
            tmp.put(k, v);
        }
    }
    *self = tmp;
}
```

Alternatively, using `pop`.

```rust
fn resize(&mut self, chains: usize) {
    let mut tmp = SeparateChainingHashST::new(chains);

    while let Some(table) =  self.st.pop() {
        for (k, v) in table.into_items() {
            tmp.put(k, v);
        }
    }
    *self = tmp;
}
```